# xTerm.js in WKWebview encounters characters disappeared on iOS 15

Tags: ios15, xtermjs

The problem just appears on xTerm.js combine WKWebView. The Safari and SFSafariViewController on iOS 15 are fine.

Comparison video: https://youtu.be/R30yMe5Riao
Demo code: https://github.com/dongyg/Bug-xTerm.js-WKWebView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set rendererType: "dom" in your terminal settings.

Comment: It is worked. Problem solved. Thanks.